# Is the set of irrational numbers between 0 and 1 closed? open? compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

$S = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash\mathbb{Q}: 0 \leq x \leq 1 \}$. How would you prove if S is closed or not. I know that there are infinitely many irrational numbers between 0 and 1, and that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, but would that help?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** What's the limit of the sequence $\left(\frac1{n\sqrt2}\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$?

Answer (score 0):

Q is dense in R if every point of R is either a limit point of Q or belongs to Q. When you form the irrational numbers, you're just removing some of the real numbers (all the rationals). Since between any two real numbers is an irrational number, what does this tell you? Note you can always find a sequence of irrationals converging to any rational.